# bind ip to subdomain

Tags: subdomain, bind, ip

I have a linux client that reports his ip adress to a server who writes the ip down in a mysql table.
Now my question is how to bind this ip adresse to a subdomain in the moment it is submitted by the client?
i heard about the Linux DNS Bind but the addresses their are declared static in a file called "named.conf" if im getting it right...
How would you solve it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

DNS servers like bind allow for dynamic dns updates from DHCP servers and the like: https://www.isc.org/software/bind/documentation/arm95#dynamic_update and here is the RFC mentioned: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2136.txt

I guess technically it's a host to IP address A record you actually want to create.